# Differentiate between a dangerous redirect and an irrelevant ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, redirect

On my web page it is possible to send ajax requests and then jump to another page meaning that the AJAX requests are irrelevant and are aborted by the browser. The return from one of these jquery AJAX requests to an error handling might be:

```
readyState = 0
responseText: ""
status=0
```

But, note the error handler may not be even invoked. It depends when the browser aborts the request and when the user selects to go onto another page. If it is invoked it is invoked with the above parameters.

Here is where it gets juicy.  A similar response happens when a 302 redirect is returned from an AJAX request when the location is set to another domain.  The browser (both IE And FF) mangle the 302 and invoke the error handler with the same info:

```
readyState = 0
responseText: ""
status=0
```

I know it is a 302 with location set to another domain from using fiddler. But take fiddler away and all you see is above.

I need to be able to differentiate between

- ajax requests that are aborted because user goes to another page
- ajax requests that are aborted because they are redirects to another
  domain

But I can't if I get the exact same info for both.

Any tips? Could I check a window object or something else in the DOM?  Note: I can't predict when a request will return a 302. I also can't see the `location header` server side.

Comment: Do the parameters `textStatus` and `errorThrown` have the same values in both situations as well?

Comment: @zeroflagL Yes they have the values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When a response to $.ajax is 301, can I programmatically get the new URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391410/when-a-response-to-ajax-is-301-can-i-programmatically-get-the-new-url)