# Ajax url moved via 301 and request throws error

Tags: ajax

I use this script, to get some data via ajax request:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $urlpre = document.location.protocol;
    $.ajax({
        url: $urlpre+'//domain.tld/file.php',
        error: function (thrownError) {
            pushNotify('Could not connect to update server!', 'danger', '5');
        },
        success: function (data) {
            ...
        }
    });
});
```

Now the url changed from `domain.tld/file.php` to `sub.domain.tld/file.php`.
I set up a 301 redirect and in the browser this works fine, but the ajax request throws me the error.
I tried to google the issue, some have problems with http: and https:, but I don't think that's my case.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391410/when-a-response-to-ajax-is-301-can-i-programmatically-get-the-new-url

Comment: Do you get any errors on the browser's console?